# Issue with `-sds` naming convention in gdal_translate

Tags: geotiff-tiff, file-formats, gdal-translate

I'm converting ~100 .hdf files to .tiff using gdal and getting some unfortunate naming conventions when using `-sds`

`for %A in ("...\*.hdf") do gdal_translate -of GTiff -sds "%A" "%A.tiff"`

However, it appears that it is first converting the files and then separating the subdatasets, therefore giving me file names like .tiff1, .tiff2, etc (completely useless).

Any suggestions on how to fix this within the same piece of code or with a simple second step?

Comment: There is a ticket for this up on GDAL trac, perhaps some attention there will get a fix committed: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5119

Comment: We have submitted this issue to the gdal programming staff and they have fixed the issue within the software. Shouldn't be a problem from now on and should give file names aaa1.tiff, aaa2.tiff, etc rather than aaa.tiff1 and aaa.tiff2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to figure this one out in powershell. Using the following code, I was able to just add .tiff on to the end of my files and can rename them later to preserve the naming conventions that I'm interested in.

`Set-Location -Path (path)`

`dir | % { mv $_.FullName ( $_.Name + “.tiff” ) }`

Hope this helps others.

Comment: this was fixed in gdal_translate, it will be in the next major release.